# Is there a population density map of pre-Columbian South America?

Tags: native-americans, demography, maps, south-america, precolumbian-era

I have found such maps for North America, e.g. [this one](https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/attachments/precol-jpg.212199/):
[image]

But never for the southern continent. The goal is a broad overview. How many Lokono were there, compared to the Mapuche (and the Cree for that matter)? I am generally curious what places were considered "urban" in South America, especially outside the Inca Empire.

A map of primary subsistence (agrarian, hunter-gatherer, etc.) of that continent would also be helpful.

Comment: What is the provenance of that image? The figures shown seem to me far too low to reflect Pre-Columbian population estimates in the few tens of millions, as some historians believe to be the case. The illustrated population densities in Greenland also appear too high.

Comment: It's literally unknown at the moment insofar as I'm aware. For instance there was a presumed [Arawak civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arawak) around the Orinoco river valley that went on to colonize the Caribbeans (among other places), a [Marajó civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marajó) around the Amazon delta, and just last year they found a gazillion [new Maya ruins](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-42916261). It's basically a work in progress.

Comment: Also, your source for that map (alternatehistory.com) is sketchy at best.

Comment: The forum thread that that map is drawn from appears to be [this one](https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/threads/substantial-mestizo-population-in-british-america.289149/page-3), but it doesn't cite the provenance so it's not much help.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My source is actually [this page](http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/twimberley/EnviroPhilo/PreColumbianMaps.htm), which features a collection of maps that appear to be from the same source. It's not stating where they originally came from, or the year they depict, so the map isn't all that great per se, but it serves as some indication of relative populations and is a starting point for better research.

Comment: @Denis Thank you for your response. If that little is known, I guess I should ask a new question, "what were the biggest urban centres in South America in the year 1500 outside the Inca Empire". Though that may be marginally better Googleable, so I'll try that first.

Comment: @KeizerHarm: however answerable what you suggested is through googling, that would likely be a good question that it'll make it to the hot network questions list if you phrase it well IMO.

Comment: Have you read _1491_?  I don't have my copy handy but a lot of this is covered (from a 2006 base of understanding)... don't recall the extent of the maps tho. https://www.amazon.com/1491-Revelations-Americas-Before-Columbus/dp/1400032059 One of the assertions that I found most interesting is that the Amazonian 'wilderness' was basically a type of 'garden', highly shaped by man.

Comment: @AllInOne 1491 was the very thing pursuing me to do more research in the subject. A wonderful book, and I still haven't finished it. I was just hoping for a more comprehensive overview of the various civilisations, Mann doesn't go over them one by one but mentions a couple specific ones to make points.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Since you read _1491_ you know there is plenty of debate over the numbers....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what this website defines as history (roughly, "the story of humanity"), there's rather a lot of "pre-Columbian history" in South America, and you can't really depict it all in a single map. Population density maps for 6500BCE, 3500BCE, and 1491 AD would all look quite different from each other. For the purposes of the rest of the answer, I'm going to assume you are interested in something closer to 1491AD.

The pre-Columbian Americas have been criminally understudied at this level of scope and detail IMHO. Of course there isn't much of a pre-Columbian written record, so a certain amount of that is understandable. That being said, Colin McEvedy and Richard Jones did an amazing [worldwide study of historical human population history](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/624253.Atlas_of_World_Population_History), which included the following map in their section on The Americas:

[image]

<sup><sub>This image is from McEvedy and Jones' Atlas of World Population History. This book is out of print and almost impossible to find for purchase, but if you can, do it. [Online at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/atlasofworldpopu00mcev).</sub></sup>

This may not go down to the level of detail you like on who those people were, but I have seen immediate pre-Columbian language maps of South America that could perhaps be reconciled with this. Couldn't find one on a really quick search, but I know I've seen them online.

Calibrating it against the North America map you posted, it doesn't have nearly as much detail, and appears to be missing a fair bit. In particular, these days I'd expect to see a higher density in the Pacific Northwest, which M&J aren't showing. Their map I believe is likely older, so less likely to include recent research. So it might be wise to consider what it shows to be a floor, not a ceiling.

For your theoretical question, McE&J postulated about 13 million souls in the Americas (north and south) at this time, and based on this map the vast majority of them would have been living in the Azetc and Incan areas. The area of North America the Cree and Inuit were inhabiting (Canada/Alaska) may look large enough to make up for their low density, but this map projection artificially inflates that area.

The modern northern states of South America, along with the tropical coast of Brazil, appeared to have some level of farming going on as well. It may not show well in the map, but I know that farming was moving up the Caribbean islands at this time as well (probably from South America), and had made it as far as parts of Cuba.

Comment: Isn't this site's working definition of "history" the analysis of written records? With everything prior to that some mixture of *prehistory* and *archaeology*? How do you reconcile that with your statements '*"pre-Columbian history" in South America*'? Also, under what legal system is the free will of historians ever "criminal" in regards to their choice of sub-discipline and specialization?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - If you check our [Help Center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "Human Prehistory" is specifically **on** topic, while "General (non-human) Prehistory" is specifically **off** topic. So that's the official written dividing line for our scope. But of course the real dividing line is what users decide to close and what they don't.

Comment: Two additions http://faculty.washington.edu/timbillo/Readings%20and%20documents/ABRIDGED%20READINGS%20for%20PERU/Denevan%20The%20Pristine%20myth.pdf nicer colour version in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252077825_Effects_of_Syn-Pandemic_Reforestation_on_Atmospheric_Carbon_Dioxide_From_1500_to_1700_AD

Comment: about part of the confusion about 'where agriculture stops': Brazilian Indians cultivated mostly manioc - an edible root that grows when buried in the ground. It is not hunther-gathering, but it is not a 'farm' or 'plantation'. No plows, animals, slaves or specialized farmers needed - the tribes were small, it was mostly self-subsistence. There was much rain, so no permanent large scale irrigation systems or raised fields were needed.  The question is if you want to call this agriculture or not, as the Inca/Aztec had much more developed systems.

Comment: @LangLangC - I don't think either of those maps would be useful additions to this answer, as neither have any indication of actual population density. However, they are freaking *great* for showing archeologically interesting sites, and the latter one's highlighting of the Neolithic (agricultural) zones is worth checking out for anyone interested in this subject. (And Luiz may be interested to know the latter map appears to have counted Brazilian manioc use as agriculture)

Comment: It's a bit puzzling that not even "1491: New Revelations of the Americas Before Columbus" by Mann refrains from offering such a map like the one above. But the OP-map is from 'alternate-history' and my guess is that the colouring in that map has a bit of illusory precision of guesstimates.

Comment: @LangLangC - Yeah, I'd be really surprised if there was a significant amount of people in the Amazonian interior engaging in agriculture. I'd prefer maps to show large swaths of unfarmable territory like that as holes rather than color them in.